# clang:how can fdebug-prefix-map use new path relative to user home path `~`?

Tags: gcc, gdb, clang, lldb

I try rewrite the source file path to `~/src/lib` by using `fdebug-prefix-map`.

I can confirm `DW_AT_decl_file` is rewritten to something like `~/src/lib/path`.

But the result is lldb can't find the source file. If I change to a absolute path, it works fine.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `target.source-map` setting to remap location of source files. From `(lldb) apropos source-map`:

> Source path remappings are used to track the change of location between a source file when built, and where it exists on the current system.  It consists of an array of duples, the first element of each duple is some part (starting at the root) of the path to the file when it was built, and the second is where the remainder of the original build hierarchy is rooted on the local system.  Each element of the array is checked in order and the first one that results in a match wins.

The usage looks something like:

```
(lldb) settings append target.source-map /foo /bar
```

Note that you use `append` here instead of `set`, because otherwise you'd overwrite the mapping every time you add an entry. You can check the mapping with:

```
(lldb) settings show target.source-map
```